# How to show div and css content when clicking on a image area map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this issue, where i am trying to show the css/div in the area coordinate position of where I have clicked. Essentially i would like to show that div on the position of the area assigned. Mostly like a click and show information based on the area click

```js
(function($) {
  $('.list-group area').on('click', function(e) {

    $('.' + this.id).toggleClass('show');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.dropdowntest-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

area {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<map class="list-group" name="map"> 
    <area id="section-1" class="list-group-item" shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,200" />
    <area id="section-2" class="list-group-item" shape="rect" coords="242,194,393,288" />
    <area id="section-2" class="list-group-item" shape="rect" coords="397,24,530,109" />
</map>

<img alt="Picture1" src="https://placehold.it/680x466" height="466" width="680" usemap="#map" data-cms="{'contentId':95875}" />

<div class="dropdowntest-content  section-1">
    <p>Hello world 1</p>
</div>
<div class="dropdowntest-content  section-2">
    <p>Hello world 2</p>
</div>
<div class="dropdowntest-content section-3">
    <p>Hello world 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows the `dropdowntest-content` on the cursor position:

```js
(function($) {
  $('.list-group area').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.' + this.id).toggleClass('show').css({top: e.clientY, left: e.clientX });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.dropdowntest-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

area {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<map class="list-group" name="map"> 
    <area id="section-1" class="list-group-item" shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,200" />
    <area id="section-2" class="list-group-item" shape="rect" coords="242,194,393,288" />
    <area id="section-2" class="list-group-item" shape="rect"  coords="397,24,530,109" />
</map>

<img alt="Picture1" src="https://placehold.it/680x466" height="466" width="680" usemap="#map" data-cms="{'contentId':95875}" />

<div class="dropdowntest-content  section-1">
  <p>Hello world 1</p>
</div>
<div class="dropdowntest-content  section-2">
  <p>Hello world 2</p>
</div>
<div class="dropdowntest-content section-3">
  <p>Hello world 3</p>
</div>
```