# Is it possible for an <area> to open a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, area

```js
//Search in the HTML document for id Modal, id ModArea and class close
let modal = document.getElementById("Modal");

let btn = document.getElementById("ModArea");

let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// when ModArea is clicked
btn.onclick = function() {
  //make the modal visible
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
// when X is clicked
span.onclick = function() {
  //remove the modal
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<img class="europe_img" src="https://mapswire.com/download/europe/europe-political-map-miller.jpg" usemap="#europe" alt="Europe">

<map name="europe">
    <!--Create an area for Iceland -->
    <area id="ModArea" target="" alt="Iceland (ISL)" title="Iceland (ISL)" href="" coords="138,388,35,540,232,748,549,585,516,374" shape="poly">
    <!--Create a modal -->
    <div id="Modal" class="modal">
        <!--Content of the modal: paragraph and closing button -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Modal Success</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</map>
```

i'm doing a project where I need to divide Europe in many different areas and put a couple of statistics about each country, since there are a lot of them I was thinking of creating a template modal and to fill the gaps using json, but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried simply making a modal and replacing the button section with the area section, but when I go and test it it shows only for a split-second before returning to the normal page.

Anyone has an idea on how I could solve this? (it's not strictly necessary to solve it with a modal, just anything that would let me show the informations on the same page in a sort of pop-up mode, instead of having to go to a different page altogether

Comment: You can give any element a unique id and just attach event handlers to it with Javascript. Like `document.getElementById('some_id').addEventListener('click', function(e){ ... });`

Comment: What specifically did you try and what specifically didn't work as expected?  Please update the question to include a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853624/how-to-show-div-and-css-content-when-clicking-on-a-image-area-map

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution: the problem was that `href` would still activate even if it was `=""` (something I didn't know), so by just removing that and adding `cursor: pointer;` in css I can achieve the same effect and not have the pop-up immediately disappear.